# validating C:\Users\xyz\docker-compose.yml: services.app.build.args must be a mapping

Tags: docker, docker-compose

While building Docker image using `docker-compose build` I'm getting `validating C:\Users\xyz\docker-compose.yml: services.app.build.args must be a mapping` error.

This is the docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - DEV=true
    ports:
      -"8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

Can someone answer this why am I getting this error?

I checked the docker-compose.yml file but It seems to be correct.

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message says? I.e. change `- DEV=true` to `DEV: "true"`?

Comment: There's a missing space in the `ports:` line which I'd expect to cause some sort of error, but not this one.  In Compose file version 3, [`args:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#args) is documented to be only a list and not a mapping, which matches what you have in the file.